# mysqldump --add-drop-procedure or DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS

Tags: mysql

I need to use mysqldump with `replace` instead `insert` and not dropping database and table when restoring.
But I need to dropping and recreate triggers and stored procedures

For that I use mysqldump with `--replace` and with `--skip-add-drop-table` parameters and I have replaced `CREATE TABLE` with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST` (with str_replace() in php)

When I try to restore I got error `trigger already exists`

I have solved that by adding `--add-drop-trigger` parameter

But now I have another error: `PROCEDURE already exists`

I've searched some like `--add-drop-procedure` but it seem to not exist

I have seen in my exported.sql file and I found some like this

```
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my_test_procedure` */;
```

But seem to be commented so not work

Here is the entire code:

```
mysqldump --replace --skip-add-drop-table --skip-comments --add-drop-trigger --hex-blob --routines  -u$user -p$pass -h localhost -P 3307 bd_name tbl_name > path_to_export/exported.sql
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

> But seem to be commented so not work

This is **not** a comment.  It only looks like one.

```
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my_test_procedure` */;
```

This format means "execute this statement only if you are a MySQL server, and only if your version is 5.00.03 or later."

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html

You will notice that `mysqldump` files are packed with similar-looking statements, all of which are executed normally.

Comment: Ok. Is good to know that ... but then if is executed why got this error: `PROCEDURE already exists` ?